# Can anyone identify this two pin locking plastic low voltage plug and socket?

Tags: connector, identification, plug, socket

This is a plug/socket from a reset button on a gas heater. I need to extend the cable because it requires the heater facia to be removed to access it, so I wanted to create a new plug/socket to add an additional extension button.

The only problem is I have no clue what kind of plug/socket/connector it is. I originally thought Molex, however this doesn't appear to be the case as the pins are not shielded on the plug side. It seems to be more JST style, but my google-fu is lacking right now with this one.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I guess if I cannot find what kind it is I could always replace the original plug/socket, but I'd rather avoid changing the OEM parts or splicing into the wires destructively.

Thanks!

[image: Images of connector]

Answer (score 3):

It is standard JST [SM series](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=238) wire-to-wire connector. Probably the cheapest and most ubiquitous connector out there.